# is pk valid as an absolut id? (Django)

Tags: mysql, django, uuid

after deleting the last model, the next model that will be created will be assigned the deleted model pk, which means that any links to the deleted model will now point to the new model.

So should we use PK or create a UUID? 
e.g user profiles, some high-level profile will point to some completely new profile when deleted.

- this site, stack-overflow uses PK for questions, i wonder if what i'm writing will apply here as well

Comment: "after deleting the last model, the next model that will be created will be assigned the deleted model pk" You sure about that? Have you tested it? If so, what DB are you using? Postgres, at least, wouldn't have this behavior, it would keep incrementing the ID regardless of what was deleted. I'm not sure about the other DB backends.

Comment: i tested it several times, localhost Django sqlite, maybe in production with a MySql it want have this behavior, i'll check, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the simplest sense, a database uses a counter for a PK field and increments it when a new record is added. Delete/update operations do not modify the counter. So it is impossible for the db to use the same value twice.

EDIT: OOps, this seems to be a feature of Sqlite. Details are here: http://sqlite.org/autoinc.html

To quote the docs:

> If no ROWID is specified on the insert, or if the specified ROWID has
>   a value of NULL, then an appropriate ROWID is created automatically.
>   The usual algorithm is to give the newly created row a ROWID that is
>   one larger than the largest ROWID in the table prior to the insert.

And:

> The normal ROWID selection algorithm described above will generate
>   monotonically increasing unique ROWIDs as long as you never use the
>   maximum ROWID value and you never delete the entry in the table with
>   the largest ROWID.

Comment: When testing locally using - 'django.db.backends.sqlite3' as the Database it indeed uses a deleted pk for new models. on production, or at least when using MySql The PK increments as expected and are always unique

Answer (score 0):

You can, in fact, from the [same link](http://sqlite.org/autoinc.html) learn that creating `AUTOINCREMENT` on your primary key stops this nuisance.

Try:

```
CREATE TABLE "Pity" (
"ID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL);
```